# My server is not accepting the JSON data I am sending through retrofit2

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I am sending a `JSON` data to Server.

I'm trying to post `json` data using `retrofit2` but getting some unexpected fatal error.

`JSON` should look like

```
{
   "lab_details":[
      {
         "floor":1,
         "lab_name":"Lab-1",
         "lab_capacity":100,
         "lab_switch_count":2,
         "ecid":306
      },
      {
         "floor":2,
         "lab_name":"Lab-2",
         "lab_capacity":230,
         "lab_switch_count":3,
         "ecid":306
      },
      {
         "floor":2,
         "lab_name":"Lab-3(Computer Lab)",
         "lab_capacity":300,
         "lab_switch_count":5,
         "ecid":306
      }
   ]
}
```

Activity API CALL looks like

```
plda.setLab_details(pldArray);
Gson gson = new Gson();
final String s = gson.toJson(plda);
System.out.println("after string " + s);
postLabDetailsApiClass.getLab().labcall(s).enqueue(new Callback < postLabDetailsResponsePojo > () {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call < postLabDetailsResponsePojo > call, Response < postLabDetailsResponsePojo > response) {
    Log.d("Req", s.toString());
    Log.d("Responses", response.body().toString());
   }
```

Server is not accepting the JSON

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ecava_proto1, PID: 19308
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.ecava_proto1.postLabDetailsResponsePojo.toString()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: please post here the `JSON` that you send to your server so we can compare to the expected `JSON`.

Comment: I have posted the JSON above. Server accepts only in that format. But I am not able to convert my objects

Answer (score 0):

`response.body().toString()` causes `NullPointerException` because `response.body()` appears to be `null`. Perhaps your server response has no body. You mentioned that you are trying to post this JSON on the server, which means that **it's part of the request, not response**.

Comment: it should be in the comment part

Comment: I am getting response body as null. Tell me how to fix that.

Comment: @bitanmaity37 how to fix what exactly? remove `Log.d("Responses", response.body().toString());` line causing trouble. Your code works, just the server doesn't return the JSON in the response, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: The server returns status and message as a JSON. That is why I am doing that :P

Comment: @bitanmaity37 apparantly it doesn't return JSON in its body, since it is null.